# jQuery's .get() stole my elements. Ok, but why?

Tags: jquery, dom, methods

So I have been brushing up on my jQuery and have been playing with the `.get()` method.  I understand that you can use it to put `DOM` elements into an array like `$('p').get();` and then access their properties for example `console.log($('p').get(0).innerText);`.  But I also noticed that when I tried to grab some elements, put them into an array and output them somewhere else it actually removed them from the `DOM`.

### For Example

```js
   var input = $('ul#input li').get();
    $('ul#output').append(input.reverse());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <ul id="input">
        <li>1 in line</li>
        <li>2 in line</li>
        <li>3 in line</li>
        <li>4 in line</li>
        <li>5 in line</li>
        <li>6 in line</li>
        <li>7 in line</li>
        <li>8 in line</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul id="output"></ul>
```

`.get()` took the `li` elements and put them into an array I `reverse()` the array and output to another `ul`

**the Question**
I would like to know why it removed them from the `DOM`?  Is it "just because", I'm cool with that. After `googling` it for awhile I thought I would come and ask the experts.  There is no bug here, only trying to understand how the method works.  The [API](https://api.jquery.com/get/) didn't cover this.

Much appreciated to anyone that can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's intended behavior. Any kind of DOM manipulation (`.append()`, `.prepend()`, `.insertAfter()`, etc.) methods takes the passed instance and places it where you're defining (you can't have a single DOM node located in two+ places at the same time).

If you're looking for the behavior you're expecting, call `.clone()` first so you have a fresh copy to place where you'd like. This will retain the first instance (one found within `ul#input`) while allowing you to place another instance in your desired location (`ul#out`).

```js
$('ul#out').append(
  $('ul#in li').clone().get().reverse()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="in">
  <li>1st Item</li>
  <li>2nd Item</li>
  <li>3rd Item</li>
</ul>

<ul id="out">
</ul>
```